# Git how to avoid the detached head when working on older branches

Tags: git

How can I work on older branches without the detached head issue:
I am using this repo(https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-dessert-pusher) and the way it is structured is that all branches converge to master.

So if I say checkout Step.04 I get a detached head., should I just keep ignoring it maybe?

I am not planning on pushing anything to the repository just for my own local use want to know what would be the best way to work on this.

Many thanks.

The way repo is structured is this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create local a branch where you want to start working. `git checkout -b temp old-revision` or whatever. **personal opinion warning**: Either way, `detached HEAD` is **not** and issue... it's actually one of the best features of git cause you don't need a local branch in order to be able to work (like in your case, old stuff). As long as you know what you are doing, it's all fine.